# Quarkus uber-jar not running with primefaces

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces, quarkus

I migrated a project that created a WAR file (with JSF and PrimeFaces) for Wildfly, to a Quarkus application, using the quarkus-primfaces-extension.

The application is running fine in dev mode when start it via maven quarkus:dev. 
But when I build and run it as an uber-jar, as soon as I call the main page, I get the following error:

```
SEVERE org.apache.myfaces.application.ApplicationImpl.createComponent(1282) [executor-thread-1] - Undefined component type org.primefaces.component.Growl
jakarta.faces.FacesException: Undefined component type org.primefaces.component.Growl
        at org.apache.myfaces.application.ApplicationImpl.createComponent(ApplicationImpl.java:1283)
        at org.apache.myfaces.application.ApplicationImpl.createComponent(ApplicationImpl.java:1252)
        at jakarta.faces.application.ApplicationWrapper.createComponent(ApplicationWrapper.java:128)
        at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.tag.faces.ComponentTagHandlerDelegate.createComponent(ComponentTagHandlerDelegate.java:587)
        at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.tag.faces.ComponentTagHandlerDelegate.apply(ComponentTagHandlerDelegate.java:275)
        at jakarta.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.apply(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:52)
        at jakarta.faces.view.facelets.CompositeFaceletHandler.apply(CompositeFaceletHandler.java:47)
        at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.tag.faces.core.ViewHandler.apply(ViewHandler.java:195)
[...]
```

I'm using:

- Quarkus version 3.0.4.Final,
- quarkus-primefaces 3.13.3
- myfaces-quarkus 4.0.1
- quarkus-omnifaces 4.2.1
- JDK 17

Any ideas why this happens?

Regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quarkus in Uber-JAR mode is not supported by MyFaces.
See: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MYFACES-4427

Comment: Also listed in the Quarkus Faces issues as a known issue: https://github.com/melloware/quarkus-faces/wiki/Quarkus-Faces-Known-Issues#uber-jar

Comment: Thanks a lot. Don't understand why I haven't found this page myself....